# Table format and output in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

Can anyone give me any hints on how to output this table in R (link)? for example, how to bold the first line, add a dotted line , and make a double title for the table.   I prefer R markdown, rft is also OK , I am trying to avoid Latex . Thank you so much!!

[image]

Comment: You cannot do that with markdown for sure. Use LaTeX or HTML, although that dotted line does not seem to be a widely used standard for me. Anyway, you should come up with a minimal reproducible example if you hope to get any answer, such as your data/model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way using the `htmlTable` package

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('gforge/htmlTable')
```

(you can also find `htmlTable`, the function, in the Gmisc package on cran (`install.packages('Gmisc')`), but it will be removed soon and available in a stand-alone package called `htmlTable`)

```
out <- 
  structure(c("37(34%)", "1 (Ref)", "1 (Ref)", "1 (Ref)", "1 (Ref)", 
              "1 (Ref)", "45(23%)", "0.68 (0.63, 0.73)", "0.38 (0.32, 0.44)", 
              "0.21 (0.17, 0.28)", "0.08 (0.05, 0.13)", "0.05 (0.02, 0.11)", 
              "", "0.03", "0.04", "0.03", "0.02", "0.02", "110(34%)", "0.68 (0.65, 0.71)", 
              "0.38 (0.34, 0.42)", "0.21 (0.18, 0.25)", "0.08 (0.06, 0.11)", 
              "0.05 (0.03, 0.08)", "", "0.03", "0.04", "0.03", "0.02", "0.02"
  ), 
  .Dim = c(6L, 5L), 
  .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("r", "hr", "p", "hr", "p")))

## format rows/cols
colnames(out) <- c('(n = ***)','HR (92% CI)','P','HR (92% CI)','P')
rownames(out) <- c('PD No (%)','None','Age','Age (<60 vs > 60)',
                   '&emsp;Age > 60','&emsp;Age < 60')

## add padding row called subset
out <- rbind(out[1:4, ], 'Subsets:' = '', out[5:6, ])

## bolding rownames
rownames(out) <- sprintf('<b>%s</b>', rownames(out))

## table column headers (with line breaks (<br />))
cgroup <- c('', 'R + C<br />(n = ***)', 'R + S<br />(n = ***)')

# zzz <- `rownames<-`(out, NULL)

library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(out, rowlabel = 'Adjustment<sup>&dagger;</sup>', 
          ctable = TRUE, align = 'ccccc',
          ## number of columns that each cgroup label spans:
          n.cgroup = c(1, 2, 2), cgroup = cgroup,
          ## insert two table spanning sections:
          tspanner = c('',''),  # no labels
          n.tspanner = c(4, 3), # number of rows to span (must sum to nrow(out))
#           css.tspanner.sep = "border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;",
          caption = "Table 1: Hazard ratios and <i>p</i> values of two models and
                     something something.", 
          tfoot = '<font size=1><sup>&dagger;</sup>Some note.</font>')
```

Gives me this

[image]

Ran into problems (headaches) with the dotted line. suggest just using a solid

Comment: It works very well!! The output is an html page, is there any way to convert/output it into a Word file?

Comment: I usually keep things in html/latex and (hackily) put into word when I need to (for one because I don't do it often enough to find a better way; and two I haven't found the transition from html/latex to word to be easy). There are some other options: 1) [pandoc with examples](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html); 2) using the correct [yaml front matter](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html) at the top of your .rmd files; 3) (what has worked best for me) copy/paste directly into word/excel and edit if needed (usually easier to add after than getting it perfect in rmd)

Comment: if you are using rstudio, you can also copy/paste directly from the html viewer which is handy for quick/dirty tables but, of course, not reproducible

Comment: Thanks, looks like copy/paste is the easiest one :)

Comment: The dotted line can be added through the argument `css.tspanner.sep = "border-top: 1px dotted black"` although the viewer has trouble displaying it correctly (I've filed a Chrome bug report for this). You should also instead of the `rbind(out[1:4]...)` I suggest you set the tspanner to `c('', 'Subsets:')` and the n.tspanner to `c(4, 2)`.

Comment: ah, I was getting half dotted and half solid in the viewer, I think. learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

You could use package `ReporteRs`. There are output examples and corresponding R code [here](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/flextable_examples.html).

You have control over table borders, fonts, paragraphs, etc.